# Можно ли округлить функцию распределения?

Tags: математика, теория-вероятностей

У меня есть функция F(2.2857) (по табличке нормального распределения надо знать часть в формате целая_часть.десятичное и часть 0.остаток_до_сотых), можно ли округлить её до F(2.29)? Или надо отбрасывать 5 и 7, чтобы получилось F(2.28)?

Comment: Есть разные варианты округления - в меньшую сторону, в большую... Обычное округление - если следующий отбрасываемый разряд >= 5, то в большую сторону, если меньше - в меньшую. Так что ваше округление - 2.29. Только вот вы же говорите не о значении функции, а о ее аргументе. Если есть табличные значения до сотых - я бы смотрел F(2.28) и F(2.29) и интерполировал, а уже потом отбрасывал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При каждом действии, если число имеет цифры после сотых, округляем по всем канонам округления, то есть, если есть Ф(2.2857), то округляем до Ф(2.29) и ищем значение в таблице нормального распределения. Если Ф(2.2417), то округляем до Ф(2.24) и также ищем значение в таблице нормального распределения